# c# DB Related error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

Here is the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Personal-PC;Initial Catalog=LocalDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=google;Password=google" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is Code Behind:

```
public string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ToString();

public void ExecuteSQL(string sqlstring, List<SqlParameter> sqlparam)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection();
        objsqlconn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        if (objsqlconn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            objsqlconn.Close();
            objsqlconn.Dispose();
            objsqlconn.Open();
        }

        SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, objsqlconn);
        int i, cnt = sqlparam.Count();

        for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
            objcmd.Parameters.Add(sqlparam[i]);
        objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And I got following error.When i am try to insert a data into sql table .Actually what is the meaning and how to solve this error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
       at DBdml.DBACC.InsertUpdateDeleteSQLString(String sqlstring, List`1 sqlparam) in D:\dotnet\ASP.netC#\BusinessLayer\DBACC.cs:line 78
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Just look at the message "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."

Comment: @user2721764, yes but you have to assign that connection string to your `SqlCommand`object.

Comment: @user2721764: All objects are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle. That could be the reason. Show in which method you assign the `ConnectionString` and where you use the connection. The code above wouldn't compile because `connectionString` is a field.

Comment: Because you're reconstructing the object every time you could replace `if (objsqlconn.State != ConnectionState.Open)` with `if (true)`

Comment: Now you have omitted the field `connectionString`. As an aside, you should use `throw`(or omit the `Catch`) instead of `throw new Exception(ex.Message)` to keep the original stack trace including line numbers.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need `WebConfigurationManager` instead of `ConfigurationManager`.

Comment: ... and here the link to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178411(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Not really sure but try `connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;`

Comment: @Habib: I guess that would be the better solution, but it works. Just tested it.

Answer (score 2):

This sequence is gonna kill you:

```
objsqlconn.Close();
objsqlconn.Dispose();
objsqlconn.Open();
```

You can't use a connection object once you've disposed it. Really, you can greatly simplify that entire method:

```
public void ExecuteSQL(string sqlstring, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> sqlparam)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, objsqlconn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlparam.ToArray());
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's so simple we all missed it. You didn't lose your programming skills yet ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `WebConfigurationManager` instead of `ConfigurationManager` to read from a `web.config` file.

The how-to is [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178411(v=vs.100).aspx) and just involves replacing the name of the class in your case.